Error in IF statement - coding a discord bot in python
First time asking a question on here, so please bear with me.
I am writing a discord bot, and need users to input at least 2, and up to 10 teams for an attendance type check-in. The code/bot works perfectly if users input 10 teams. However, if a user only inputs say 2 teams, I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'.
I technically understand what is causing this error: since the user only input 2 teams, the variable team3 has a value of "None" and is thus not a discord.Role class and has no .name member.
However, I am not sure why I am receiving this error. Why does the "TeamNames.append(team3.name)" part of code still get evaluated when the IF statement is false?
Code Extract:
@bot.tree.command(name="assign_teams", description="Enter the roles for the teams that will show up in your check-in")
async def assign_teams(interaction:discord.Interaction, team1:discord.Role, team2:discord.Role, team3:discord.Role=None, 
                       team4:discord.Role=None, team5:discord.Role=None, team6:discord.Role=None, 
                       team7:discord.Role=None, team8:discord.Role=None, team9:discord.Role=None, team10:discord.Role=None):
    global TeamRoles
    TeamRoles = [team1, team2, team3, team4, team5, team6, team7, team8, team9, team10]
    if team3 != "None": TeamNames.append(team3.name)
    if team4 != "None": TeamNames.append(team4.name)
    if team5 != "None": TeamNames.append(team5.name)
    if team6 != "None": TeamNames.append(team6.name)
    if team7 != "None": TeamNames.append(team7.name)
    if team8 != "None": TeamNames.append(team8.name)
    if team9 != "None": TeamNames.append(team9.name)
    if team10 != "None": TeamNames.append(team10.name)
    a = datetime.datetime.now()
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Success!", description=f"{str(len(TeamNames))} Teams added!", 
                          colour=discord.Colour.dark_purple(), timestamp=a)
    embed.add_field(name="Teams:", value=TeamNames)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)

I tried:

writing the IF statements with normal indentation.
using a pass statement

What I expect:
I only need/want to use the Role.name member of the role (and not the Role.id). When a user only inputs say 5 teams, I expect the other 5 teams to have a value of "None" (which is the case), and that when the IF statement sees the "None" value, it will not try to append the Role.name member (because it isn't there).
*apologies if I used some terminology incorrectly

EDIT:
I have solved the problem. The IF statement was comparing the contents to the string "None". Once I removed the quotation marks, the code worked as expected
i.e.
if team3 != None: TeamNames.append(team3.name)

